# How to convert values in specific column into integer type under numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

How can I convert the **second** column of this matrix into `int` type *inplace*?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1.23e+02, 2.3], [1.3e+01, 2.9],[1.2e+01, 83.3]])
```

Desired output:

```
array([[ 123. ,    2],
       [  13. ,    2],
       [  12. ,   83]])
```

The best I can come out with is this, but not inlace

```
x[:,1].astype(int)
```

Comment: You can't change the typing of the array in-place (unless I'm grossly mistaken), but you can floor.

Comment: Only one `dtype` per array, either all `int` or all `float`. (or all `object` to allow both `int` and `float`, but that's idiotic: you'll loose all of numpy numerical performance...)

Comment: Why do you need to convert it, and why does it need to be 'inplace'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the typing of the array in-place, but you can truncate (or floor if you prefer):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1.23e+02, 2.3], [1.3e+01, 2.9],[1.2e+01, 83.3]])
>>> np.trunc(x[:,1], x[:,1])
array([  2.,   2.,  83.])
>>> x
array([[ 123.,    2.],
       [  13.,    2.],
       [  12.,   83.]])
```